# Dropdown list control display System.Bytes[]

Tags: asp.net, mysql

This is unexperienced problem that I am facing. .Net Dropdownlist control showing 
`System.Bytes[]` the data taken from MySQL DataBase, and SP query is

`Select concat('(', cast(AccountID as varchar), ')') as AccountID`

AccountID is bounded with DropDownlist control.

Comment: what is the code lines you used to bind the dropdown?

Comment: Sorry I have not seen your Mysql tag, I have checked in SQL server.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. According to [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37485) this is not a bug and you should try:

```
Select cast(concat('(', AccountID, ')') as CHAR) as AccountID
```